# WP8 LockScreen.SetImageUri exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, lockscreen

LockScreen.SetImageUri method fails with ArgumentException when I use the following uri:

```
LockScreen.SetImageUri( new Uri("C:\\Data\\Users\\DefApps\\AppData\\{2F102375-2740-441C-BF2F-808608F47DA1}\\Local\\Wallpapers\\my_wallpaper.jpg",UriKind.Absolute));
```

I have checked with Windows Phone Power Tools that the image exists and it's size also fits. The path is correct, because I can create a StorageFile from the above path.

**So why is this exception thrown by SetImageUri method?**

If I use the "ms-appdata:///local/Wallpapers/my_wallpaper.jpg" it works correctly, however this kind of uri does not work with StorageFile and StorageFolder.

Answer (score 0):

"ms-appdata:///local/" is the uri scheme you must use, what do you mean with " this kind of uri does not work with StorageFile and StorageFolder"?
"local" points to your app folder. If you create a file there, you can access it with that uri scheme.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Localfolder